# How to set nested JSON data to datatable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

My JSON data looks like this and I am trying to get it sent through datatables.

```
{"data":[{"code":"001","name":"TEST",
"drpList":[{"name":null,"bed":"xxx","mbed":null},
{"name":null,"bed":"eeee","mbed":null}]}]}
```

I can't figure out how to look passed `drpList`, etc and go straight for the data. This is what I have so far. Anyone think they could help?

```
$('#table').DataTable({
        "ajax": url,                                                                        
        "bDestroy": true,                                                                       
        "columns": [
            {"data": "code"},                                                               
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "drpList.name"},
            {"data": "drpList.bed"},                                                                                        
            {"data": "drpList.mbed"},
            {"data": null,"defaultContent":editview}
        ],
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthChange": false 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to see the json that is passing `drplist` with array that means you access it using the `drplist.0.columnname` for the first array as so on from drplist.

For nested list you need to prefer the Link https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html that may be help you.

I Found the Answer.. when you want to print all the data then you can use the delimeter and print the all data of Array...  **(use below code)**

to get all value of array `dataobjectofarray[delimeter ].columnname`

```
$('#table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "Hello.php",
                    "bDestroy":true,                                                                        
                     "columns":[
                        {"data": "code"},                                                               
                        {"data": "name"},
                        {"data": "drpList[| ].name"},
                        {"data": "drpList[, ].bed"},                                                                                        
                        {"data": "drpList[, ].mbed"}
                        ],
                        "language": {
                        "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
                        "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                        "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                        },
                        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                        "lengthChange": false 
    });
```

Comment: it's working but it display only one value.i mean 001,TEST, ,xxx, . Second value missed.

Comment: Please Mark as Answer

Comment: but issue still getting

Comment: i am getting **TEST 001 |  1234567890, 1234567891 IFSC, IFSC1**. but i want line by line, i mean **TEST 001  null 1234567890 IFSC. TEST 001  null 1234567891 IFSC1**